# I am unable to render images in MarkDown

Tags: markdown, github-pages

I am using permalink to render images using markdown in the following format:

```
![ABC](https://github.com/username/reponame/blob/1234/Assets/Images/Image_Name.png)
```

In preview, it comes up but not after it is published.

Any other better way to nail this?

Answer (score 0):

You're right doing so should work.

> In preview, it comes up but not after it is published.

Do mean that it is shown the code instead of the image? If this is the case, have you tried giving a blank line before and after the image? Like this:

```
Text
   
![ABC](https://github.com/username/reponame/blob/1234/Assets/Images/Image_Name.png)

Text
```

Otherwise if you meant that the image is not rendered and in its place appears the image of a question mark, maybe you have a problem with the link (e.g. a typo or permalink of an image in a private repository).

If none of this works maybe try a different approach. Remember that HTML tags are allowed in Github markdown:

```
<img src="https://github.com/username/reponame/blob/1234/Assets/Images/Image_Name.png"/>
```